# Why does Zoom need the Flash, when he has another?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

So Zooms goal is to steal the Speedforce from Barry Allen

> because he is dying due to his use of velocity 6
>  The man in the iron mask is revealed to be Earth 3's Jay Gerrick, aka
>  earth 3's Flash, whom Zoom is keeping prisoner.

Why not simply take another earths Flashes Speedforce, why go though all this hassle for Barry's?

Comment: Hunter wanted to and that's why he defeated Jay; but couldn't use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *The Race Of His Life* (S02E23), Zoom handwaves an explanation. Zoom *tried* to steal the speed force from the other speedster, but it just "didn't take". No further explanation is given.

From [the transcript](http://transcripts.foreverdreaming.org/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=27364):

> *Joe*: So you brought him here to steal his speed.
>
> *Zoom*: **I tried, but it wouldn't take.**

Answer (score 4):

In the comics, Jay Garrick is one of the few speedsters who was not connected to the Speed Force. He got his powers from inhaling "hard water" fumes, which we must assume was a chemical compound very different from the real world version. He was always much slower than the rest of the Speed Force-fueled Flashes.

It's possible that the TV version of Jay from the TV had a similarly alternative origin that rendered his particular form of speed incompatible to Zoom's absorption process.